# Getting STDerr and STDout into a log file inside of a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdout, stderr

I was wondering if it is possible to get all of what is outputted from a script I have made to go to a log file if they change one of the variables in the script. Example, in the script a variable `createLog=true` could be set to enable logging.

I know I can do `./myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee sabs.log`

But I would like to be able to simply run `./myscript.sh`

and have the whole script logged in a file, as well as output to the console if the var is set to true.

Would I have to change every command in the script to accomplish this or is there a command I can execute at the beginning of the script that will output to both.

If you need more details please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`exec` without an argument lets you redirect for the remainder of the current script.

```
exec >log 2>&1
```

You can't `tee` within the redirect but you can display the file with a background job.

```
tail -f log &
```

Comment: You can use `exec` to redirect to a process substitution: `exec > >(tee sabs.log) 2>&1`.